# Relation between Set of Best Responses and Set of Dominating Responses - Explanation of Correlation Case

Tags: game-theory

From Strategy by Joel Watson, Page 58:

> The key to the analysis has to do with  whether a given player’s
> belief is thought to exhibit correlation between the  strategies of
> this player’s multiple opponents. One can define Bi  so that
> correlated conjectures are not allowed. Then one can let Bci be the
> version in which correlation is allowed. The general result is

[image]

Author's notation: Bi is the set of best responses and Bic is the version with correlation allowed. UD is the set of dominating responses.

I don't understand the theorem specially the correlation part, can anyone please explain it with an example? I am not sure if the author is referring to correlation between different beliefs of one player or correlation between the set of all beliefs of all players. An example would really help

Comment: Appendix B of that book goes over an example and partially proves the quoted result (p.421-425). Did you check that out?